# Add woocommerce subscription to laravel collection rest api

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have this code in my controller, I wish to add some details of the subscription to the $questionnaire collection.

I am using the Codexshaper Library for laravel https://github.com/Codexshaper/laravel-woocommerce
Retrieving the subscription works I have tried, but it only retruns 10 rows

> $subscriptions =
> Subscription::options(['include'=>$test->toArray()])->get();

`dd($subscription['status'],$subscription['line_items'][0]->name);` works, that the data i want to add

If i remove the dd() and try to reach my blade i would get this error

> Error: Identifiant non valide.
> [woocommerce_rest_shop_subscription_invalid_id]

Also, this doesn't seem the best way as I would call the woocommerce rest api many times, I haven't a way to pass a list of ids to retrieve only specific orders

```
    public function getIndex(Request $request)
    {
        $questionnaires = Questionnaire::with('member','type','profils.profil')->paginate(30);
            foreach ($questionnaires as $questionnaire) {
                $subscription =Subscription::find($questionnaire->id_subscription);
                $questionnaire->status = $subscription['status'];
                $questionnaire->duration = $subscription['line_items'][0]->name;
            }

        return view('questionnaire.questionnaires')->with([
            'questionnaires' => $questionnaires
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: It seems it happens when an order id doesn t exist

Comment: Pass filter[posts_per_page]=100 in the request URL